# python 2.7 - argument as name to following argument

Tags: python, python-2.7

```
import argparse
def add(number_one = 0,number_two = 2):
    a = int(number_one) + int(number_two)
    return(a)

def Main():
    parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
    parser.add_argument("n1", help = "first number", type=float)
    parser.add_argument("n2", help = "second number", type=float)
    args = parser.parse_args()

    result = add(args.n1, args.n2)
    print(str(result))

if __name__  == '__main__' :
    Main()
```

Hello, I am learning argparse so I write this simple program that sums two number.

```
python add.py 3 5
```

I want the program to do the same, but with argument that defines next argument. For example:

```
python add.py --n1 3 --n2 5
```

Comment: Do you mean that you want `n2` to be unavailable until `n1` has been parsed?

Comment: You just want the `python add.py 3 5` ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to add `--` before `n1` and `n2`.  Example:

```
parser.add_argument("--n1", help = "first number", type=float)
parser.add_argument("--n2", help = "second number", type=float)
```

You can also add a short-option:

```
parser.add_argument("--n1", "-1", help = "first number", type=float)
parser.add_argument("--n2", "-2", help = "second number", type=float)
```

This way, you can call your program with, for example, the `-1` option instead of writing out the *incredibly* long option `--n1`.

Answer (score 1):

The needed change is easier than you'll think: Simply replace

```
parser.add_argument("n1", help = "first number", type=float)
parser.add_argument("n2", help = "second number", type=float)
```

with

```
parser.add_argument("--n1", help = "first number", type=float)
parser.add_argument("--n2", help = "second number", type=float)
```